# How can I get AppleScript to click a button or link on a webpage?

Tags: hyperlink, click, applescript

I am trying to get an Apple Script to click on an item within webpage. This script  below works somewhat, I can get it to click different safari tabs or drop down menus, but I cannot get it to click an item within webpage.

In this example, I am trying to get the script to click the "Im feeling Lucky" button from google.. it all works except the click for some reason:

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
tell application "System Events"
tell process "Safari"
    open location "http://google.com"
    click at {655, 382} -- {from left, from top}
end tell
end tell
```

The location of the button will likely be different depending on screen size, but anyone have any idea why this is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess it's because the page hasn't loaded yet. Try adding a delay after you call `open location`. Using Javascript to click the button would be more flexible, you can do something like this:

```
tell application "Safari"
  open location "http://google.com"
  delay 1
  do JavaScript "document.forms[0]['btnI'].click()" in front document
end tell
```

Comment: Boy that was quite obvious. Thanks so much!